# How to call a C# method from a HTML input range within ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a small question: I have a range slider & I would like to call a method in my back end `.cshtml.cs` file.

I am creating an ASP.NET Core web app & this is my markup:

```
<form method="post">
     <input type="range" min="1" max="100" asp-page-handler="Volume" asp-route-level=""/>
</form>
```

What I would like to happen is when this slider is changed the method `Volume` is called with the current level of the slider. For buttons I have used the `asp-page-handler` but this doesn't seem to work for an input tag.

I'm brand new to HTML & asp.net so any help would be much appreciated. Below is the method I have in my `.cshtml.cs` file for reference

```
public void OnPostVolume(int level)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"The Level Is {level}");
}
```

Comment: Make your server a CONTROLLER where the routes are the application like VOLUME.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: The input does not have submit behavior. Even if it did, or forced one, do you really want to do a request/response page load every time the slider is moved? I think you will want to wire up a javascript event to the input and and call a controller via ajax techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Crowcoder said, the default input doesn't have submitted behavior. I suggest you could use ajax with httphanlder for the razor page to achieve your requirement.

The example like below:

```
<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" />
<script>
    document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("input", function () {
        var value = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index?handler=SliderValueChanged",
            data: { value: value },
            success: function (result) {
                // Handle the response from the server
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Razor page like below:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    
    public IActionResult OnPostSliderValueChanged(int value)
    {
        // Perform any necessary operations with the slider value
        // ...

        return new JsonResult("Success");
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]